# Better approcach to use Sqlite for several plaforms (ARM, x64 and x86)?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I use Visual Studio 2012 for a typical LOB app. This app has DAL, BLL and UI layers.

All projects, excepts the Sqlite, are based on Portable Class Library (PCL), so I can compile once and they work for all platforms.

However the database is Sqlite. Sqlite uses native code, so I need to deploy a package for each platform.
For example, when I need to deploy for ARM processors, I need to recompile all projects (more than 20) for ARM because Sqlite is placed in the lower layer. Most of projects depends directly or indirectly of the DAL, where Sqlite is placed.

Which would be the best approach to solve this scenario?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you include a native library in your app, you need to build a separate package for each platform, so that each one includes the right library for the platform.

If you're not already using [SQLite for Windows Runtime Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e), you should. It adds SQLite as an extension to your add reference dialog. If you add it to your project from there, the native library for the right project will be automatically included every time you make a build.

To access the native library from .NET you can use [sqlite-net](https://nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net) which is platform independent.

Since you're using PCL, it's possible that you're not writing your app only for WinRT. In this case the answer might not be totally applicable but I'd need more information to give you a more specific advice.

Comment: I am using SQLite as extension, so I get some improvements in the building process because I can change the project platform without manually updating the references to SQLite. However, the Data Access project that used SQLite is referenced by other assemblies as BLL and others. Since I need to define explicitly the platform for the Data Access project, the extension system does not solve my problem. Maybe I would need to create a kind of extension with my Data Access project, imitating the system used by SQLite. By the way, my target platforms are Windows 8, WinRT and Windows Phone 8.
Thanks

Comment: @DabielKabuto You could create a project with Data Access interfaces and reference it by all other assemblies that depend on it. All these assemblies could now remain platform agnostic. For each target platform you would then implement this interface using platform specific code. In the main project for the target platform the bootstrapping code will make sure the right data access implmentation will be used (injected). This way the only platform specific projects should be individual data access implementations and the main projects for each target platform.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [web page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) about SQLite for .NET.

There's a version of the SQLite.dll that is platform-independent. It will dynamically load an additional DLL that has the platform-specific, native code. They propose the following directory layout (within your application directory):

```
System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly)
System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only LINQ assembly)
x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly)
x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)
```

In your project, you only add the platform-independent, managed-only DLL. For that reason, you can compile it once and it should run on all platforms. There's no hard link from the managed-only to the native DLLs. This is only resolved at runtime.

Hopefully, this approach can be extended to the ARM architecture.

Please not that the page also contains mixed-mode assemblies, assemblies dynamically linked against some VC runtime library etc. You'll want to avoid them. They cause a lot of head aches.

Comment: `System.Data.SQLite` can't be used in WinRT because it is an ADO.NET provider and there is no ADO.NET available in WinRT.

Comment: Yes, as Damir says, this solution cannot work in my scenario. My target platforms are Windows 8, WinRT and Windows Phone 8. This approach, the Interop, works for full the .Net Framework, not for WinRT